# Jquery Mobile: updating a form more than once

Tags: jquery-mobile

OK, after many hours of confusion I have discovered that calling page() on Jquery Mobile elements only works once.

What do I do if I want to update a form multiple times via AJAX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**update**

jQuery Mobile beta2 introduces a `create` event.`.trigger('create')` applies JQM enhancements to an element and its children.

See: http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html

---

You have to use it only once for an element. No exceptions yet.

if `$('#container')` is your element, and you replace its content with AJAX, then there are two things you can do:

1. call `.page()` on `$('#container').children()`
2. empty the container and create a div inside of it, and call `.page()` on it.

The second option is better if your content needs to be wrapped (like a list) and I'd recommend it in general.

If you are using a listview or something take a look at `.listview('refresh')` or other dedicated methods.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this.

Are you saying that if I destroying the element and then recreating it will allow me to call page() on it again?

Although I'm using checkboxradio('refresh'), this doesn't seem to work properly. Each individual checkbox element is redrawn, but they don't realise they are all part of the same checkbox group and don't style accordingly. (ie. there is a gap between each checkbox item, rather than collecting them together with rounded corners on the first and last element).

Jimmy.

Comment: Do they render correctly if you put them in HTML? If yes, you should try calling whatever needed to repaint on the parent element. if not, they are treated separately. To put it differently - to make it work you need to repaint parent element, not the checkboxes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

After several workarounds that did not meet my needs, I found this particular statement: remove or overwrite an existing div and call .page() on new div. This works best if content has to be reloaded / re-rendered / refreshed more than once.