# Force a refresh on a Jquery Mobile controlgroup button on small screen display

Tags: button, refresh, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile controlgroup with two buttons:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="headerMenu iconposSwitcher">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="barcode" data-iconpos="left" class="EANView">EAN</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="style" data-iconpos="left" class="styleView">Style</a>
</div>
```

On larger screens (PC, iPad) I want the text to show ~ data-iconpos="left".
On smaller screens (Mobile, Smartphone) there is little space, so I don't want to display the text ~ data-iconpos="notext"

I can use the "refresh" function on select-menus. Is there a similar way to refresh controlgroups or button elements?

I tried it like this, changes iconpos, but does not rebuild the button.

```
    if ($('body').width() < 275)
      {
      $(".iconposSwitcher a").attr('data-iconpos','notext');
      $('.headerMenu').controlgroup('refresh', true);
      }
```

Thanks for hints & Rgs

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
$(".iconposSwitcher a").removeClass('ui-btn-icon-left').addClass('ui-btn-icon-notext');
```

Easier than thought...

**EDIT:**

For div elements (controlgroup with `input`):

```
$(".iconposSwitcher-div a").attr('data-iconpos','notext').removeClass('ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-right').addClass('ui-btn-icon-notext');
```

Comment: I always come back to my questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For buttons, use the `buttonMarkup()` method instead of `controlgroup()`

In general, I prefer the usage of the `page()` method, see this post

[Jquery Mobile: updating a form more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362127/jquery-mobile-updating-a-form-more-than-once)

Comment: This doesn't work... $(".iconposSwitcher a").attr('data-iconpos','notext').page();  I prefer page() though.

Answer (score 4):

maybe its too late but for those who come here with same question:
You can use `.trigger('create')` on any Element to trigger 'Create' event to do JQM magic on elements.

Comment: have you tried? Controlgroups are pretty tricky. See [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4773)

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it this way:

```
$button = [YOUR CONTROLGROUP DIV]

$button.find('a').button();

$button.controlgroup();
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is calling controlgroup() twice; once to initialize, next to refresh, eg:

```
// refresh group
$('#checkboxes').controlgroup().controlgroup('refresh');
```