# How can I generate elements after page load with jQuery Mobile Alpha 3?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating some collapsibles after the page is loaded via ajax/json.
The problem is that jQuery Mobile has already loaded, so the added classes and elements aren't created.

In Beta 3, I guess I could just use .trigger('create') and it would fix this for me, however that wasn't around in Alpha 3.

How can I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: upgrade to the beta or even 1.0 when released would be the wise option. After that you could keep that version as it's supported but sticking with a alpha version IMHO is not the way to go

Comment: Understandable... but I don't have any control over that :).

Comment: you are developing/working on the project so you have input. I would suggest talking to who does have control and push for the change. I know there might be some push back but again IMHO it's better to use the supported version than an alpha. To help your case things like performance, features and device support have increased and bugs have decreased in the newer version. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/ has some great points as well. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with Phil, you should definitely upgrade.

However, if this is out of the question for you, try the page() method, see

[Jquery Mobile: updating a form more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362127/jquery-mobile-updating-a-form-more-than-once)

Comment: I ended up doing this: `$('div[data-role=page]').page("destroy").page();` It's messy, but it works. Thanks, everyone :).